# Why this python script is giving wrong output,using awk and comapring value in if block?

Tags: python, linux, shell, if-statement

I want to get desktop notification whenever load is more than  five,for that I have written this python script but it is giving opposite to expected

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands

a=commands.getoutput("cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'")
float (a)
print a
if (a > 5.00):
    commands.getoutput('notify-send "Hello world!" ')
else:
    print "load looks fine!!"
```

Can someone rectify this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the typecast float value back to `a`. A plain print to console can be deceiving since you will not be able to tell if the variable is a float or not. So you can use `type` to confirm

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands

a = commands.getoutput("cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'")
a = float(a) # assign back to a
print a, type(a)
if a > 5.00:
    commands.getoutput('notify-send "Hello world!" ')
else:
    print "load looks fine!!"
```

Comment: ohh !!! I was expecting that calling float () will typecast it.
Thanks.

Comment: Is a subprocess with a UUOC calling awk REALLY the right approach for this in python? I don't know python but seems to me like it can probably at least read the contents of a file...

Answer (score 1):

Getting the first token from a file is easy to do natively in Python.  There is no reason to call `awk` (let alone then [`cat` and `awk`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)) and wastefully create a subprocess chain for this simple thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import commands
with open('/proc/loadavg') as load:
    a = float(load.readline().split()[0])
if a > 5.00:
    commands.getoutput('notify-send "Hello world!"')
else:
    print("load looks fine!!")
```